# Having trouble getting Ariel Flesler's ScrollTo working

Tags: jquery, plugins, navigation, scroll, scrollto

I've been trying to implement Ariel Flesler's ScrollTo plugin, but I can seem to figure out how to initiate it. This is his website:

http://flesler.blogspot.com/

What I would like to do is have a static navigation, and when the user clicks a nav link, the content scrolls within a particular div. I have a pretty good understanding of jQuery, and it seems like this plugin should be really easy to use, but the documentation kinda sucks for demonstrating how to actually use it.

Comment: Sounds like it'd be simpler to use jQuery `.animate()` than a whole plugin for what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Peter is right, you can do this:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {

          if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')

          && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var $target = $(this.hash);

            $target = $target.length && $target 
            || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
   if ($target.length) {

              var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;

              $('html,body')

              .animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);

             return false;

            }

          }

        });

      });
```